# How can I use S-curve(sigmoid) in mutivariate nonlinear regression in R?

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

I am working on Market Mix Modeling - 
I need to capture impact of different marketing variables on sales of a product through `s-curve`. Below is the equation I need to use -

```
sales = 1/[1+exp((a1-TV)/a2)] * 1/[1+exp((b1-Radio)/b2)] * ...(other-variables)...
```

I tried NLS but kept getting starting value error. Then-after, I used self start function in `nls - Sslogis` but it could be used on only one variable at a time and not the whole function as stated above.

How can I fit more than 1 `sigmoidal(s-curve)` function in a nonlinear regression model?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please carefully read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and then update your question to conform with these guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Without a full dataset it's hard to tell. I've had a similar problem so what I did was use tryCatch in a for a loop.

```
For (i in 1:10){

        tryCatch(nls(y~SSlogis(x[,i],rest of the arguments..),error=function(e) 0)

}
```

This will replace the error with a 0 which would mean no fit could be made.

You can replace the errors with anything. 0 made the most sense for my data.